# In-App Purchases Swift Game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, in-app-purchase, storekit

I've looked at the other answers on this site and can't seem to find anything that really works. Could anyone either point me in the right direction on how to purchase/restore a single product for a SpriteKit game? Thanks!

Comment: that is a very good direction: https://developer.apple.com/in-app-purchase/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find a good tutorial here at the Apple Docs: [Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Restoring.html)
Hope that helps,
Julian